# Passing an array of classes to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having difficulty passing an array of class to an function which needs to operate on members of the classes, what I mean to do the code below should explain.

```
class Person {
  public:
    char szName[16];
};


void UpdatePeople(Person* list) //<- this is the problem.
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        sprintf(&list[i]->szName, "whatever");
    }
}

bool main()
{
    Person PeopleList[10];
    UpdatePeople(&PeopleList);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `&` you can directly pass the array

```
UpdatePeople(PeopleList);
```

In this call `PeopleList` will decay into a `Person*`

Then in your `UpdatePeople` function you can use this as

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    sprintf(list[i].szName, "whatever");
}
```

I would, however, recommend using the C++ standard library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Person{
public:
    std::string szName;
};

void UpdatePeople(std::vector<Person>& people)
{
    for (auto& person : people)
    {
        std::cin >> person.szName;
    }
}

bool main()
{
    std::vector<Person> peopleList(10);
    UpdatePeople(peopleList);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: *smacks forehead*. thanks for that. solved my problem alright.